# Rails - Devise/Acts-as-taggable-on Gems - Make tag ownership unique to a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, acts-as-taggable-on

A user can log-in ([devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem), create a text post, & tag that post (via [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem). If a tag is used more than once across posts, the CSS of that tag changes. In the example below, for instance, the underline style on #foobar disappears. However, as it stands, this is happening across user accounts. This means the tags a user inputs to tag their posts are not unique to their account. In other words, if **User1** tags **#foobar** and after, on a separate account, **User2** also tags **#foobar** - the underline goes away on both user accounts. My goal is to make the tags a user inputs in the posting form unique to that user.

Example:

**User1** Account

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgIQ8.jpg

**User2** Account

http://imgur.com/29gzutj

I have tried lots of solutions - none of which are working!! Please help!

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

 def index    
    if params[:tag]
     @posts = current_user.posts.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order(created_at: :desc)
    else 
     @posts = current_user.posts.includes(:things).all.order(created_at: :desc)
    end 
 end 

 def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
 end

 def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
        redirect_to '/posts'
    else
        render 'new'
    end

end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<button id='addtext'>text</button>

<%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
 <%= f.fields_for :things do |ff| %>
<% end %> 

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="posts">
  <%= render @posts %>
</div>
```

**_post.html.erb**

```
<div class="post">
   <%= raw post.tags.order("taggings_count DESC").map {|t| link_to t.name, tag_path(t.name), class: css_class_for_tag(t.taggings_count)}.join(' ') %> 

   <% post.things.each do |thing| %>
     <%= thing.try(:text) %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

**post_helper.rb**

```
module PostsHelper
 def css_class_for_tag count
  case count
   when 1 
     'new_tag'
   else
    'used_tag' 
   end
 end
end
```

**post model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  ActsAsTaggableOn.delimiter = ' '
  ActsAsTaggableOn.force_lowercase = true
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :things, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :things, allow_destroy: true 
end
```

**thing model**

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "300x300>", medium: "600x600>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
  has_many :posts 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160303110608) do

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "tag_id"
 t.integer  "taggable_id"
 t.string   "taggable_type"
 t.integer  "tagger_id"
 t.string   "tagger_type"
 t.string   "context",       limit: 128
 t.datetime "created_at"
end

add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string  "name"
 t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
end

add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true

create_table "things", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.text     "text"
 t.integer  "post_id"
 t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
 t.integer  "order"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
 t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
 t.string   "reset_password_token"
 t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
 t.datetime "remember_created_at"
 t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
 t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
 t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
 t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
 t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
 t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: I'm not understanding - what is the desired result? Do you want the tag counts to be specific to how many time a _user_ has used a tag?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Yes specific to a user. Basically, if User1 uses a tag in the posting form, that should't have any bearing on User2 using that same tag.

Comment: Ok, I have an answer I think will work. Posting it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
tag_counts = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.joins(:taggings).
  where(taggings: { taggable_type: "Post", taggable_id: current_user.post_ids }).
  group("tags.id").count
```

Gives you something like this:

```
{ 7=>2, 1=>2, 5=>4 }
```

The first number is the tag id, the second number is the number of occurrences of that tag for current_user.

Now you can do this:

```
<div class="post">
  <%= raw post.tags.map{ |t| [t.name, tag_counts[t.id]] }.sort_by{ |t| -t[1] }.
                    map{ |t| link_to t[0], tag_path(t[0]), class: css_class_for_tag(t[1])}.join(' ') %>
</div>
```

This can be written more expressively, but it gets longer than... ;-)
Basically we loop over the post's tags, just as we did before, but then connect each tag with its count specific to current_user in the first map statement. Then we sort by the count, in reverse order. And in the final map statement we generate the links, as we did before, just using the user specific count again.

Comment: You would have to load all the taggings / tag counts this way, though.. rather than just the taggings / tag counts for the tags in the post

Comment: Unfortunately, the edit causes this error "undefined local variable or method `post'" - extracted source "where(id: post.tags.pluck(:id))". Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Actually I reverted my edit. I overlooked that you anyway load all posts for the current user. Then it is not inefficient to load all counts Jay. Actually you need them all anyway. So just assign the counts once before you render the posts.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `taggings_count` attribute on the `tags` table increments whenever any `tagger` uses a tag. So you need to come up with a new query.

You can get the data you're looking for by making a select on taggings table, make some table joins so that you can just select taggings that were made by a specific user, and from that you can get the counts you're looking for.

I wrote a query to demonstrate the structure you would need:

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_taggable
   ActsAsTaggableOn.delimiter = ' '
   ActsAsTaggableOn.force_lowercase = true
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :things, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :things, allow_destroy: true

   def tags_with_user_specific_counts
     query = <<-SQL
       SELECT taggings.tag_id,
              tags.name,
              count(taggings.id)
         FROM taggings
         INNER JOIN tags
           ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id
         WHERE taggings.tagger_id = '#{user_id}'
           AND taggings.tagger_type = 'User'
           AND taggings.taggable_id = '#{id}'
           AND taggings.taggable_type = 'Post'
         GROUP BY taggings.tag_id, tags.name
     SQL
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query).to_a
   end
 end
```

The only thing to note is that I haven't written this one using the ActiveRecord way, so this produces an array of hashes with the data you want:

```
[{"tag_id"=>"1", "name"=>"jim", "count"=>"1"},
 {"tag_id"=>"2", "name"=>"bob", "count"=>"2"}]
```

But if you really wanted this to return `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag`s, I think it would be possible.

EDIT - this post was updated to run the query using `taggings.tagger_id`. A previous version of this post suggested running this query:

```
   def tags_with_user_specific_counts
     query = <<-SQL
       SELECT taggings.tag_id,
              tags.name,
              users.id as user_id,
              count(taggings.id)
         FROM taggings
         INNER JOIN tags
           ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id
         INNER JOIN posts
           ON taggings.taggable_id = posts.id
           AND taggings.taggable_type = 'Post'
         INNER JOIN users
           ON posts.user_id = users.id
         WHERE users.id = '#{user_id}'
         GROUP BY taggings.tag_id, tags.name, users.id
     SQL
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query).to_a
   end
```

Comment: Oh actually I thought of a way to simplify the query! I will rewrite.